# mapping one json property to two different fields in java (jackson)

Tags: java, jackson

This is what i tried, but i get null for firstName field

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstractor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User{

      @JsonProperty("name")
      private String name;
      @JsonProperty("age")
      private int age;

      private String firstName;

      public void setFirstName(String name){
        this.firstName = this.name.substring(4,10);
      }
}
```

lets say that i have json that i want to map to the above POJO, the problem is i want to use the @JsonProperty("name") for both name and firstName, but set the firstName slightly differently.

Comment: 1. do you call the setFirstName() function in your code? 
2. I wouldn't assign the firstname with a substring since names can be quite different in size.

Comment: no, this just an example, what i want to do was say save the initial, but use name field. or may be save a truncated version of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the '[JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html)' Annotation

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstractor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User{

      private String name;
      private String firstName;

      @JsonProperty("age")
      private int age;            

      @JsonSetter("name")
      public void setNames(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.firstName = this.name.substring(4,10);
      }
}
```

Comment: Annotation has been un-deprecated